# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class

Tags: android, build.gradle

I had this exception I've tried everything on internet but it didn't work

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class

My **Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itdeveapps.customaim"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')



    compile ('com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile ("com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar"){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}


}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check lib folder. I had same error because I have added support-v4 jar in my lib folder by mistake.